# Entity Framework cast to ObjectSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm pretty new to Entity Framework and I have a question.
Is it possible to cast/convert a type var to a strongly typed ObjectSet.

For example I would like to do something like this (this is just an example from my head, not the real code):

```
var member = from item in member
                where (age == 30)
                select item;


EF.Member mbr = (EF.Member)member;   // here I would like to cast/convert
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable of type `var` [is already strongly typed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx). In your scenario it is `IQueryable<Member>`. You can't cast it to `ObjectSet<Member>`. You should be able to cast it to `ObjectQuery<Member>`.

Comment: Thanks, I checked my code and your solution worked. I didn't realize that var worked this way. I have tried all kinds of solutions but the easiest was the correct one.                    var mbrQuery = member.FirstOrDefault();
EF.Member mbr = mbrQuery.Member;

Comment: "var is still strongly typed. It just infers the type from what you initially put in it. It is in no way dynamic typing.